# Why is my Python Regex not finding the second group?

Tags: python, regex

I have some data which I am running a regex script on:

```
data = ['python3 wrapper.py -c config/app_profile_adh_bus_trans_jrnl --env TABLE_LIST_FILE=config/adh_bus_trans_jrnl_all_tables/bus_trans_jrnl_all_tables.dat --env ENV=PROD -r|Up 25 minutes', 'python3 wrapper.py -c config/app_profile_azure --env TABLE_LIST_FILE=config/azure/arcadia_azure_ingest.dat --env ENV=PROD -r|Up 25 minutes']

table_list_names = [ re.search(r".*TABLE_LIST_FILE.*/(.*).dat.*|(.*)", element).groups() for element in data if "TABLE_LIST_FILE" in element ]
print(table_list_names)
```

This is just printing the below:

```
[('bus_trans_jrnl_all_tables', None), ('arcadia_azure_ingest', None)]
```

Curious if anyone could provide input, as to why my regex second capture group is not getting anything?

Comment: Why would it?  The left half succeeds and matches the whole string.  There's no need to check an alternative.  What were you expecting to have?

Comment: If the part before the `|` matches, the part after it (with the second group) isn't taken into account.

Comment: @TimRoberts, was expecting the capture group before the | and the capture group after the | to be captured, then outputted from .groups()

Comment: What is your question? Do you want an explanation, or do you want us to help fixing your code? If the latter, please edit the question so as to add the expected result.

Comment: The `|` is a logical OR operator, and there is shortcutting.  As soon as ANY of the alternatives matches, the regex is done.  It will never do the right half.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is identical to this.
You don't even do the regex unless `TABLE_LIST_FILE` is in the element.
Therefore the alternation is eliminated.

```
import re

data = ['python3 wrapper.py -c config/app_profile_adh_bus_trans_jrnl --env TABLE_LIST_FILE=config/adh_bus_trans_jrnl_all_tables/bus_trans_jrnl_all_tables.dat --env ENV=PROD -r|Up 25 minutes', 'python3 wrapper.py -c config/app_profile_azure --env TABLE_LIST_FILE=config/azure/arcadia_azure_ingest.dat --env ENV=PROD -r|Up 25 minutes']

table_list_names = re.findall(r"TABLE_LIST_FILE.*/(.*).dat", element) for element in data
print(table_list_names)
```

Output

```
[('bus_trans_jrnl_all_tables',), ('arcadia_azure_ingest',)]
```